# Wicket - why AjaxRequestTarget object is available only in onUpdate method?

Tags: ajax, components, wicket, behavior

I want a theoretical explanation about AjaxRequestTarget on wicket. Talking about behaviors: to create your own you **must** override onUpdate method, and **can** override other methods like onEvent, onBind etc.. but why AjaxRequestTarget object is only available in **onUpdate** method?

I want it in other methods, (specifically in **onEvent()**) because I want to validade form components. In my tests, onUpdate method not works as I want.. onUpdate (with *focusout* event) is being called only when model is changed... so it is called when I fill a TextField, for example, but not when it get's empty again..

onEvent method is called on both moments, but I can't update other components (like a label to display the feedback message to that field), because AjaxRequestTarget is not available on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior#onUpdate()` is called **only** when an Ajax request is made!

`AjaxEventBehavior#onEvent()` is called **only** when an Ajax request is made!

`Component#onEvent()` is called when some (other, most of the time) Component calls `Component#send(Sink, Broadcast, Payload)`. This might happen in both Ajax and normal/non-Ajax requests. Thus `AjaxRequestTarget` is not used in the API.

Usually the `AjaxRequestTarget` is passed as part of the Payload by the caller, in case this is done in Ajax request. This way the receiver (the Component that overrides `Component#onEvent()`) may use it if it need so:

Caller.java:

```
send(getPage(), Broadcast.BREADTH, new MySpecialPayload(target));
```

Receiver.java:

```
@Override public void onEvent(IEvent event) {
    Object payload = event.getPayload();
    if (payload instanceOf MySpecialPayload) {
        MySpecialPayload mySpecialPayload = (MySpecialPayload) payload;
        if (doSomethingWith(mySpecialPayload) {
           AjaxRequestTarget target = mySpecialPayload.getTarget();
           target.add(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Another way to get a reference to the AjaxRequestTarget from **anywhere** is: `RequestCycle.get().find(AjaxRequestTarget.class)`. If it is non-null then this is an Ajax request and you can add components to the target, pre/append JavaScript, etc.

Comment: Understanding these concepts make me fell more comfortable with the framework. Thanks, your'e a real Wicket guru

Comment: But can you tell me more about the payload? What is it in this scenarios and why I must check the instance type of it? (I dont want to create a new question cause these doubts came with your answer)

Comment: Better consult the documentation: https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/single.html#_wicket_events_infrastructure